# filtering rows by checking a condition for group in one statement only

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following statement:

```
SELECT
    (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), f1, 120)) AS ff1,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), f2, 103) AS ff2,
    ...,
    Bonus,
    Malus,
    ClientID,
FROM 
    my_table                        
WHERE
    <my_conditions>
ORDER BY 
    f1 ASC
```

This select returns several rows for each ClientID. I have to filter out all the rows with the Clients that don't have any row with non-empty Bonus or Malus.

How can I do it by changing this select by **one statement only** and **without duplicating all this select**?

I could store the result in a #temp_table, then group the data and use the result of the grouping to filter the temp table. - **BUT I should do it by one statement only**.

I could perform this select twice - one time grouping it and then I can filter the rows based on grouping result. **BUT I don't want to select it twice**.

May be CTE (Common Table Expressions) could be useful here to perform the select one time only and to be able to use the result for grouping and then for selecting the desired result based on the grouping result.

Any more elegant solution for this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Just to clarify what the SQL should do I add an example:

```
ClientID  Bonus  Malus
1         1      
1                
1                1
2                
2                
3         4      
3                5
3         1
```

So in this case I don't want the ClientID=2 rows to appear (they are not interesting). The result should be:

```
ClientID  Bonus  Malus
1         1      
1                
1                1
3         4      
3                5
3         1
```

Comment: *I have to filter out all the rows with the Clients that don't have any row with non-empty Bonus or Malus.* Can you rephrase that to what you want instead of want you don't want? I am getting headaches from that sentence :)

Comment: Sorry :). I will add an example to explain it better

Comment: Done. There is an example in the question. Please let me know if more clarifications are needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Bonus,
       Malus,
       ClientID
FROM my_table                        
WHERE ClientID not in 
(
  select ClientID
  from my_table
  group by ClientID
  having count(Bonus) = 0 and count(Malus) = 0
)
```

Comment: It's exactly what I don't want to do (look at the bold texts in my question please) - to select it twice (I have a lot of complex conditions in my "where")

Comment: Your complex conditions only need to be in the outer select. The inner select only has a having clause.

Answer (score 0):

A CTE will work fine, but in effect its contents will be executed twice because they are being cloned into all the places where the CTE is being used. This can be a net performance win or loss compared to using a temp table. If the query is very expensive it might come out as a loss. If it is cheap or if many rows are being returned the temp table will lose the comparison.

Which solution is better? Look at the execution plans and measure the performance.

The CTE is the easier, more maintainable are less redundant alternative.

Comment: i somehow have a feel about CTEs. they r not just good, they are brilliant, a few 50 times faster than self joins, a few 100 times faster than a cursor.. and im not exaggerating about the performance.. my thumbs would be for CTE even if they cloned twice.. still 25 times faster than the next best alternative

Comment: @user1974729 they perform identically to the query that you get by manually copying the CTE definition to all places where it is used. SQL Server does exactly that internally. Often this is what you want :)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified what are data types of Bonus and Malus columns. So if they're integer (or can be converted to integer), then the query below should be helpful. It calculates sum of both columns for each ClientID. These sums are the same for each detail line of the same client so we can use them in `WHERE` condition. Statement `SUM() OVER()` is called "windowed function" and can't be used in `WHERE` clause so I had to wrap your select-list with a parent one just because of syntax.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), f1, 120) AS ff1,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), f2, 103) AS ff2,
        ...,
        Bonus,
        Malus,
        ClientID,
        SUM(Bonus) OVER (PARTITION BY ClientID) AS ClientBonusTotal,
        SUM(Malus) OVER (PARTITION BY ClientID) AS ClientMalusTotal
    FROM 
        my_table                        
    WHERE
        <my_conditions>
) a
WHERE ISNULL(a.ClientBonusTotal, 0) <> 0 OR ISNULL(a.ClientMalusTotal, 0) <> 0
ORDER BY f1 ASC
```